# UITableView is displaying incorrectly first time but when i come back on that view again its displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

UITableView is displaying incorrectly first time but when i come back on that view again its displaying correctly. I have upgraded Xcode 5 to Xcode 6. I want to display table view correctly when app starts first time.

Comment: Your question is very vague. How is it displaying incorrectly? Describe what results you get when the table view first loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous person said it is very vague.  I'm guessing you are loading data sources after your table initializes.  The only solution I can give, based on the lack of information, is that you can simulate reloading your table after it loads (to basically give you the result you want).

If you executed a [self.tableView reloaddata] in the -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews method, it would solve your problem.